# df -g cronjob output to text file

Tags: bash, logging, cron, linux-disk-free

I am writing a script to write the output of df -g to a text file once a week.
here's my script, I think it should work, but whenever I try and run it as root by typing ./check_space.sh I get the following error:
./check_space.sh: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./check_space.sh: line 13:`done'

```
#!/bin/bash
#this script will run every week to grab a df -g and output it to a file.
#times to sleep
        #10080 = 1 week

#date command
NOW=$(date +"%m.%d.%y")

while true, do
df -g > /sds/app/force/custom/dumplogs/harddisk/$NOW.log

#sleep 10080
done
```

originally I was thinking of running this script in a screen session, that is why the Sleep is in there, but I quickly decided that it would be better to run it as a cron once a week.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the comma after the `true`. The correct syntax is with a semicolon: `while true; do`. But you don't need the while loop in the first place. Something like the following will suffice:

```
#!/bin/bash

NOW=$(date +"%m.%d.%y")
df -g > /sds/app/force/custom/dumplogs/harddisk/$NOW.log
```

May I also suggest that you use `%Y-%m-%d` as the date format, to make it easier to sort by date.